# Program crashes when no input is entered and button is pressed

Tags: android, kotlin, button, crash

I'm making a random number guesser game. The problem is if a user doesn't input any number and presses the button in the if condition the answerEmpty variable should be executed and the "Please enter a number" should be shown in the result text.

But the program crashes when I press the button. The else if and else condition works but the starting if condition doesn't work.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        //Calling button method
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.guessBtn)
        //Set on click listener for the button
        button.setOnClickListener {
            buttonPressed()
        }
    }
    private fun buttonPressed() {
        //Method to find view from activity_main
        val result = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.result)
        val userAnsEditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.answer)
        val userAnsText = userAnsEditText.text.toString()
        val userAnsInt = userAnsText.toInt()

        //This variable will display the answer
        val answerCorrect = "Congrats, you have correctly guessed the number"
        val answerWrong = "Sorry,you have guessed the wrong number"
        val answerEmpty = "Please enter a number"

        //Making random numbers from 1 to 10
        val randomValues = Random.nextInt(1, 11)

        //Adding a condition to check if user answer matches the random answer
        if(userAnsInt == null) {
            result.text = answerEmpty
        }
        else if(userAnsInt == randomValues) {
            result.text = answerCorrect
        }
        else {
            result.text = answerWrong
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check `EditText` text is empty or not condition before parse to in `int`

Add below condition

```
if (userAnsText.isEmpty()) {
    result.text = answerEmpty
}
```

before `val userAnsInt = userAnsText.toInt()` line.

It will fix your crash.

Your `buttonPressed()` function looks below after adding `isEmpty()` condition.

```
private fun buttonPressed() {
    //Method to find view from activity_main
    val result = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.result)
    val userAnsEditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.answer)
    val userAnsText = userAnsEditText.text.toString()

    val answerCorrect = "Congrats, you have correctly guessed the number"
    val answerWrong = "Sorry,you have guessed the wrong number"
    val answerEmpty = "Please enter a number"

    if (userAnsText.isEmpty()) {
        result.text = answerEmpty
    } else {
        val userAnsInt = userAnsText.toInt()
        //This variable will display the answer
        //Making random numbers from 1 to 10
        val randomValues = Random.nextInt(1, 11)
        //Adding a condition to check if user answer matches the random answer
        //when condition more relavant in kotlin than if-else if-else
        when (userAnsInt) {
            null -> result.text = answerEmpty
            randomValues -> result.text = answerCorrect
            else -> result.text = answerWrong
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Try catch block,
for Example

```
`

try {
    // Code that may cause an exception
    int result = 10 / 0; // This will throw an ArithmeticException
    Log.d("MyApp", "Result: " + result); // This line won't be executed
} catch (ArithmeticException e) {
    // Handle the exception
    Log.e("MyApp", "An arithmetic exception occurred: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

`
Here's a breakdown of the sections:

**try:** The code that might raise an exception is placed within this block.
**catch:** If an exception occurs in the try block, the catch block is executed. It specifies the type of exception to catch and the code to handle it.
**finally:** This block contains code that will be executed whether an exception occurs or not. It's optional.
after that your App will not Crash. it will show error you can print error in Toast or Output window.

Comment: Sorry but I'm using Kotlin and a beginner . Could you translate the code to Kotlin please?